# What was the first movie to have someone with a screen, guiding an agent on the field?

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history, trope

The whole "agent on the ground talking to a person back in the office who has the map and control of things" is a bit of a trope these days.

I just looked at Max Headroom again today and remembered now, being struck at the time it came out how cool that was. It was, probably, the first time I'd seen it.

So, what movie did that first?  Was it Max Headroom?